# Cypress - Returning an element containing multiple specific strings

Tags: cypress

I'm attempting to use Cypress for an automated test that involves verifying that an appointment's information is being correctly entered into our system. In order to locate the appointment information, I'm locating the Date and Time on a table that the user is shown, and verifying the rest of the data from there. So my primary goal is to locate the Date/Time matching the appointment info being passed into the script.

My issue is that our site renders the Date/Time differently depending on how many digits the hour slot contains. In order to maintain spacing, single-digit hours (Such as 3:40pm) include two whitespaces between the date and the time. Multi-digit hours (Such as 11:23am) only include one whitespace.

I need to locate the date/time matching what I'm passing into the function, and then search the corresponding row to ensure that all other appointment info is correct.

We've attempted using .and (Only acts as an assertion, so it doesn't return the element for us), regular expressions (Using /s+ to indicate any number of whitespaces), and for loops, but none of these are returning the element we need.

```
var apptProvider = new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    cy.get('.appointments > tbody > tr')
      .contains(Cypress.moment(apptInv[2], 'dddd MMMM Do YYYY')
            .format('ddd MM/DD/YY')
            .toString()+" "+
            Cypress.moment(apptInv[3], 'h:mm:ss a')
              .format('h:mm A')
              .toString(),
        )
      .parent()
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('td:nth-child(2)').then($providerText => {
          resolve($providerText.get(0).innerText);
        });
      });
  });
```

apptInv is an array containing the following:
0) Provider Name
1) Office Address
2) Appointment Date
3) Appointment Time

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the textual representation to narrow down an appointment here because it's complex, tricky and easily get changed. Instead, you can generate a much simpler unique key that is not affected by any UI/UX change. For example

```
<tr data-cy='${appointment.provider + appointment.date + appointmentTime}'>
....
</tr>
```

And then select an appointment with **cy.get('[data-cy=....]')**